# CASE THEN using CONCAT()

Tags: mysql, concatenation, case-when

I have a complex join part of which includes a CASE WHEN to construct a URL. This worked fine for part of the construction but I'm running into issues doing CASE WHEN when each CASE includes a Concat. Any of the several CASES I have works on its own with

```
CASE wHEN T1.Name='X' THEN Concat('A',T1.Field1)
ELSE ''
END
```

OR

```
CASE WHEN T1.Name='Y' THEN Concat('B',T1.Field2)
ELSE ''
END
```

Once I try to do

```
CASE WHEN T1.Name='X' THEN  Concat('A',T1.Field1)
CASE WHEN T1.Name='X' THEN Concat('A',T1.Field2)
ELSE ''
END
```

I get an error like

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near CASE WHEN T1.Name='X' THEN Concat' at line 5

Comment: If my memory serves me well, you have wrong syntax. Donno about MySQL, Oracle should have case ‘when condition0 then stmnt0 when condition1 then stmnt1 else end’. So ‘case’ does not repeat.

Comment: This has pretty clear examples: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to start another `CASE` function inside the first. Remove the second `CASE` and it should work:

```
CASE WHEN T1.Name='X' THEN  Concat('A',T1.Field1)
     WHEN T1.Name='Y' THEN Concat('A',T1.Field2)
ELSE ''
END
```

Comment: Also use `T1.Field1` instead of `T1,Field1`. Pay attention to commas versus periods.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yep, that's what I get for copy/pasting.

Comment: @ItsPete Man thanks, ROOKIE mistake. I'll leave this up here anyway as a guidepost